# Lotus notes. I receive the following message

Tags: lotus-notes

I need the help with lotus notes! When I start the application, I receive the following message: "NSFDbOpen: File 'C:LotusDominoDatanames.nsf' is CORRUPT - Now. How to restore it?

Comment: Lotus Notes or Lotus Domino? One is a client, and one is a Server... Where do you try to start Lotus Notes?

Comment: Does it specifically say "C:LotusDominoDatanames.nsf", or is that a name that you made up to simplify this post and hide the real name of the file?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a local file and there are no replicas/copies (either locally or on Domino servers), you may try to fix the db running either `fixup` or `compact` on it.
***(Make a copy of the affected db before you attempt next steps!)***

Client execs for both methods (there are also server versions) are located in Notes directory of Lotus install and called `nfixup` and `ncompact` respectively.

Run `nfixup -?` or `ncompact -?` to see syntax

**Warning: if no database is specified it runs on all databases!**

IBM suggests to run fixup first (you may try various options) and if this fails to try  `compact -c`  to salvage anything which is still readable (this runs a copy type compact). You may also use addtional options (eg. `-D` to discard view indexes or `-i` to ignore errors).

You may also need to run `updall` to update/rebuild view indexes after recovery.

IBM reference: (please note wherever they use `load <tool_name>` they refer to server version  - you'd use `n<tool_name>` on workstation): http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Database_Corruption_Troubleshooting_Guide